# Android - Target sdk Version = 29 but Didnt get Wifi Mac Address in API Level 33 (Android OS 13)

Tags: android, mac-address, wifimanager, android-api-33

With Android Target Version = 29, Compile SDK = 29

I got Wifi Mac Address in Android 10, 11, 12, But I can't get WiFI Mac Address in Android 13 only.

we Got Default Mac Address only 02:00:00:00:00:00.

Not Gettting Correct Mac Address Which is availabe in Wifi

**Build.gradle  File**

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.mantra.wifimacaddress"
    compileSdk = 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.mantra.wifimacaddress"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 29
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3")
    implementation("com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3")
}
```

**Get Mac Address**

```
public String getMacAddr() {
        try {
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            String ssid = info.getSSID();
            String bssid = info.getBSSID();
            System.out.println("Get SSID ====> " + ssid + " Get BSSID====> " + bssid);
            List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
            for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
                if (!nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) continue;

                byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
                if (macBytes == null) {
                    return "";
                }
                StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
                for (byte b : macBytes) {
                    //   res1.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF) + ":");
                    res1.append(String.format("%02X:", b));
                }
                if (res1.length() > 0) {
                    res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
                }
                return res1.toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "02:00:00:00:00:00";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A right MAC Address cannot be get from many years. Any non-rooted method will give only fake values. There are tons of articles online about this behaviour. It's due to privacy settings of OS. It's a security feature. It cannot be bypassed.

Comment: ok, Got it but Why I got in Android OS 11, 12. it is restricted also in 11,12 why not getting in android 13 only

Comment: It's manufacturer dependant. On my Samsung devices, without using Root, it's not possible to get any hardwre ID, MAC or Address beside the fake one. Are you sure that the MAC Address you get on Android 11 and 12 are the REALs one and not those faked created in runtime at "each" connection?